# SharePoint Online Workflow using REST API to copy List Item w/attachment to another list

Tags: rest, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I'm new to using SharePoint's REST API and using it in a SharePoint Online Workflow - web services.

I have a custom list (we'll call this, list A) that users sometimes attached documents (mostly word, excel, image files, and pdfs).

What I need to do, is copy the custom list item and its attachment to another custom list (we'll call this, list B) in the SAME site, NOT to a Document Library.  Basically, recreate the option "Copy List Item" that is available in SharePoint 2010 workflows, and was removed from SharePoint Online workflows.

I want to avoid creating and using a SharePoint 2010 workflow for this functionality.  I'm sure at some point Microsoft will be discontinued SharePoint 2010 workflows, and I'm using REST API (web services) to perform the other tasks, associated with this SharePoint Online workflow.

I found this REST API information on Microsoft's site:

url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(item id)/AttachmentFiles('file name')/$value
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken

accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" or "application/atom+xml"***

I use Fiddler 4 to test my REST API endpoints, and once I have them working, I'm able to then create a web service call in my workflow.

I was successful at getting the REST API endpoint to work in Fiddler, but I was confused with the results.  Normally, when I test my REST API endpoints in Fiddler, and click on the Inspectors tab in Fiddler, what is normally returned, is a tree like structure:

d\data\results

But I don't see that.  If I click on the Inspectors Tab, then on the HEXView subtab, I see the contents of the file.  The raw data.  I don't know how to grab this in my SharePoint Online workflow and then copy it to the target custom list (in the same site), after I have first created the list item in the target list (which I have successfully created and tested that code in my SharePoint Online workflow, using REST API - web services).

I have been able to copy a custom list attachment to a document library, and I have been able to create folders in a document library.

Stuck on copying a custom list attachment to another custom list item in the same site.

Comment: If anything, it's going the other way. 2013 WFs may be going... See the last comment here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234203/any-need-for-sharepoint-2010-workflows-in-sharepoint-2013-2016/234204#234204  Using SPD2010 workflows might be the better choice. (and they have copy Action)

Comment: I did some experimenting with the REST call from a 2013 workflow. It looks like it only accepts text back: "Unable to deserialize HTTP response content. Expected ContentType : 'application/json', 'text/plain' or 'teacxt/html', Received ContentType : 'application/octet-stream'." So, it looks like a workflow cannot receive a file via REST.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using a SharePoint 2010 workflow for now.  Will look into using Flow.